# How to use rest of spcae of Tails on USB as normal storage like FAT?

Tags: configuration, tails

I installed Tails on 8GB USB stick with [Tails Instructions](https://tails.boum.org/install/win/usb/index.en.html).

Now I have some extra space on the stick. I searched and found about [Encrypted persistent storage](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/index.en.html).

But I want to use rest of the unused space as normal storage like FAT, NTFS, ex4 etc. That means I can access USB stick from other OS (i.e. Windows, Linux or Mac).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The Tails website [strongly recommends](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/warning/index.en.html#index2h1) against doing exactly what you're asking:

> Plugging your Tails USB stick in a compromised operating system might corrupt your Tails installation, and destroy the protection that Tails provides. Only use your Tails USB stick to start Tails.